# Getting values of tuples using Bokeh rect plot

Tags: python, plot, bokeh

I am trying to use Bokeh to represent a full matrix that relates objects with their features. What I need to do is to click a rectangle (relationship) and get the value of the tuple (object, feature) associated with it.

I am trying to use a callback function, but I've managed to get only the list of objects and/or features associated  (xname and/or yname). Is it possible to get the information of the associated tuple using this type of plot (I just need the information that the HoverTool show) ? Do I need to use another type of tool or plot?

Here is the code I am using right now (after this I embed the plot using CDN and components to get script and div tags):

```
    objlist = []
    featlist = []
    bic_mtrx = np.ones((n_lines,n_cols))
    color = []
    for obj in objs:
        for feat in feats:                      
            objlist.append(obj)
            featlist.append(feat)               
            color.append("#669999")

    source = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(xname=objlist, yname=featlist, colors=color, count=bic_mtrx.flatten()))

    source.callback = Callback(args=dict(source=source), code="""

    var data = source.get('data');
    object_p = data['xname'];
    attribute_p = data['yname'];

    """)
    p = figure(title="",x_axis_location="above", tools="resize, previewsave, reset, hover", x_range=list(objs), y_range=list(reversed(feats)), plot_width=n_lines*100, plot_height=n_cols*40, toolbar_location="left")
    p.rect('xname', 'yname', 1, 1, source=source, color='colors', line_color="#000000") 

    tap = TapTool(plot=p)       
    p.tools.append(tap)     
    hover = p.select(dict(type=HoverTool))
    hover.tooltips = OrderedDict([('Tuple', '@yname, @xname')])
```

Thanks in advance.